# Shuffle song when it ends - javascript html5

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that randomizes and play a song from a list of them:

```
var sounds = [
        "sounds/royksopp.mp3",
        "sounds/9thwonder.mp3",
        "sounds/thisbeat.mp3",
        "sounds/mosdef.mp3",
            "sounds/bewater.mp3",
            "sounds/boutdre.mp3",
            "sounds/masterflash.mp3",
            "sounds/2ep.mp3",
        "sounds/drewestcoast.mp3",
            "sounds/poetry.mp3",
            "sounds/mfdoom.mp3",
        "sounds/dreams.mp3",
        "sounds/oizo.mp3", ];

function StartOrStop(audioFile) {
    srcAudio = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length)];
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    audie.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
    }, false);

    if (audie.paused == false) {
        audie.pause();
    } else {
        audie.src = srcAudio;
        audie.play();
    }
}
```

When the song stops playing, it restarts with th same one. How can I make it so when the music ends, it will grab a new song from my list and automatically play it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are simply calling `this.play()` in your `ended` event listener. Instead, you should be updating the `src` attribute with the random choice of song with `this.src = srcAudio`, similar to how you are for the initial selection:

```
function StartOrStop(audioFile) {
    srcAudio = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length)];
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    audie.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.src = srcAudio;
        this.play();
    }, false);

    if (audie.paused == false) {
        audie.pause();
    } else {
        audie.src = srcAudio;
        audie.play();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: What is the purpose of setting `.src` at `audie.src = srcAudio` within `else` statement?

Comment: Good question, but it was there in the original code, so I assume it's intended behaviour.

Comment: Is `srcAudio` within `ended` handler the same `srcAudio` set at `else` statement?